# Where can I find a code example for export the conten of a microsoft LUIS app and import it to another, using c#?

Tags: c#, azure, export, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I found the following commands (please look at the links below):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.language.luis.authoring.iversions.exportwithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.language.luis.authoring.iversions.importwithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet

However, there is no example of this. Do you have one for me? Or a better way to realize it?

Another question: How can I find the productive version of a LUIS stage?

Comment: You have links to the commands, but you  don't explain what it is you're trying to DO. Are you trying to integrate LUIS with a bot? Are you  trying to create the C# classes for a LUIS recognizer?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample usage of the import & export commands here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-dotnet-sdk-samples/tree/master/LUIS/Authoring

More specifically, here you can find the usage of the **export** functionality:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-dotnet-sdk-samples/blob/master/LUIS/Authoring/LUIS.Authoring.Sample/Pages/Management/AppExportPage.cs

And here to **import** a Luis app:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-dotnet-sdk-samples/blob/master/LUIS/Authoring/LUIS.Authoring.Sample/Pages/Management/AppImportPage.cs